# In CSV file, Based on match pattern,fetch the other value matched pattern

Tags: awk, sed, csv

Need your expert advice on this

```
AMOUNT,30,/AMOUNT,MESS,Am,/MESS,AMOUNT,30,/AMOUNT,TXN,209,/TXN  
MESS,SU,/MESS,TXN,200,/TXN,AMOUNT,70,/AMOUNT       
TXN,200,/TXN,AMOUNT,90,/AMOUNT,MESS,SUM,/MESS,AMOUNT,90,/AMOUNT
```

There is no particular order in which `AMOUNT` or `TXN` gets generated but each line has these two value. Also there is a duplicate `AMOUNT` entry on some rows.

I need an output as below

```
AMOUNT,30,/AMOUNT,TXN,209,/TXN   
AMOUNT,70,/AMOUNT,TXN,200,/TXN   
AMOUNT,90,/AMOUNT,TXN,200,/TXN
```

It will be very helpful if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Explain why each resulting record should end with `TXN`

Comment: TXN shown Trasaction status with the code success or failure... 200 shows success 209 failure....

Comment: even I can get the values that would also help...30,209  70,200  90,200

Comment: Are `AMOUNT` and `/AMOUNT` kinda working as a opening and closing "tag" for the value? Can there be _multiple_ values between `AMOUNT` and `/AMOUNT` (or between `TXN` and `/TXN`)?

Comment: no there is only one value between Amount. It was a xml file which I have changed to csv value..

Comment: Hrm... It would be easier to work with the original XML file, but never mind, this is what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F ',' '
BEGIN { OFS = FS }
{
    a = t = "N/A"

    for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i)
        if ($i == "AMOUNT")
            a = $(i + 1)
        else if ($i == "TXN")
            t =$(i + 1)

    $0 = ""

    $1 = "AMOUNT"
    $2 = a
    $3 = "/AMOUNT"

    $4 = "TXN"
    $5 = t
    $6 = "/TXN"

    print
}' file
```

This looks for the strings `AMOUNT` and `TXN` within the comma-delimited fields of each line. When `AMOUNT` is found, `a` is assigned the data of the next field.  In a similar way, `t` is assigned the `TXN` value.  If either of the values can't be found, it will be the string `N/A`.

The output is then generated.

A shorter version:

```
awk -F ',' '
{
    a = t = "N/A"

    for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i)
        if ($i == "AMOUNT")
            a = $(i + 1)
        else if ($i == "TXN")
            t =$(i + 1)

    printf "AMOUNT,%s,/AMOUNT,TXN,%s,/TXN\n", a, t
}' file
```

Only the outputting bit is different.  Instead of outputting a *record*, we output a string produced by `printf`.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda!!!! You made my day...Cheers